# WPF TreeView CheckBox Binding - How to populate ViewModel with checked boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, data-binding

I'm slightly confused about how to set up a `CheckBox` with a binding that ensures that my ViewModel is populated with all the checked fields. I have provided some of the code and a description at the bottom.

My Xaml file let's call it `TreeView.xaml`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="availableColumnsTreeView"          
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeFieldData, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SortingConverter}, ConverterParameter='DisplayName.Text'}">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Uid="HierarchicalDataTemplate_1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SortingConverter}, ConverterParameter='DisplayName.Text'}">
            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_1" Text="{Binding DisplayName.Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </CheckBox>              
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The "code behind" `TreeView.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MultipleColumnsSelectorView : UserControl
{
    public MultipleColumnsSelectorView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MultipleColumnsSelectorVM Model
    {
        get { return DataContext as MultipleColumnsSelectorVM; }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel (tried to include only the relevant stuff) `MultipleColumnsSelectorVM`:

```
public partial class MultipleColumnsSelectorVM : ViewModel, IMultipleColumnsSelectorVM
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<TreeFieldData> TreeFieldData
    {
        get { return GetValue(Properties.TreeFieldData); }
        set { SetValue(Properties.TreeFieldData, value); }
    }

    public List<TreeFieldData> SelectedFields
    {
        get { return GetValue(Properties.SelectedFields); }
        set { SetValue(Properties.SelectedFields, value); }
    }

    private void AddFields()
    {
       //Logic which loops over SelectedFields and when done calls a delegate which passes 
      //the result to another class. This works, implementation hidden
    }
```

The model `TreeFieldData`:

```
public class TreeFieldData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public IEnumerable<TreeFieldData> Children { get; private set; }
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
        }
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**

The behaviour that I want is when the user checks a checkbox, it should set the `IsSelected` property of `TreeField` (it does that right now) but then I want to go back to the ViewModel and make sure that this specific `TreeField` is added to `SelectedFields`. I don't really understand what the `PropertyChangedEvent.Invoke` does and who will receive that event? How can I make sure that `SelectedFields` gets populated so when `AddFields()` is invoked it has all the `TreeField` data instances which were checked?

Comment: I guess the MultipleColumnsSelectorVM class has a "TreeFieldData" property that returns the list of TreeFieldData objects that you see in the TreeView?

Comment: @mm8 Sorry yes, I have included that now.

Comment: @mm8 FYI: The TreeFieldData property is populated by an Initialize method which I have not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through the `TreeFieldData` objects in the `TreeFieldData` collection and hook up an event handler to their `PropertyChanged` event and then add/remove the selected/unselected items from the `SelectedFields` collection, e.g.:

```
public MultipleColumnsSelectorVM()
{
    Initialize();

    //do this after you have populated the TreeFieldData collection
    foreach (TreeFieldData data in TreeFieldData)
    {
        data.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
    {
        TreeFieldData data = sender as TreeFieldData;
        if (data.IsSelected && !SelectedFields.Contains(data))
            SelectedFields.Add(data);
        else if (!data.IsSelected && SelectedFields.Contains(data))
            SelectedFields.Remove(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works thanks, but only for "outermost" nodes. There is a list of Children as well for each TreeFieldData node so I have to recursively loop through that as well to make sure all fields have the PropertyChangedEvent attached. If that makes sense? I'm working on this now, doing the recursion in the Initialize method.

Comment: Yes, you need to iterate through and hook up the event handler for all items that you want to keep track of in the SelectedFields collection.

Comment: Yes. Could it be bad for performance to do this? Say we have a couple of hundred fields? It's only really attaching the handler, but I don't know how expensive that is

Comment: Attaching an event handler insn't that expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The subscriber of the PropertyChanged event is the view, so that if you change IsSelected programmatically the view knows it needs to update.

To insert the selected TreeField into your list you would add this code to your setter.

Also, you could define the following function which makes the notification much easier if you have many properties:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The CallerMemberName attribute instructs the compiler to automatically insert the name of the property calling the method. The ? after PropertyChanged is a shorthand to your comparison to not null.

The setter of IsSelected can then be changed to

```
set
{
  _isSelected = value;
  if (value) { viewModel.SelectedFields.Add(this); }
  else { viewModel.SelectedFields.Remove(this); }
  NotifyPropertyChange();
}
```

Of course you would need to provide the TreeFieldData with the ViewModel instance, e.g. in the constructor.

I don't know if SelectedFields is bounded/shown in your view. If yes and you want the changes made to the list to be shown, you should change List to ObservableCollection.